# Show that $Res_\underline{z=a}f(z) = -Res_\underline{z=-a}f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Given an even function of complex variable $f(z)$,

How can I show that $Res_\underline{z=a}f(z) = -Res_\underline{z=-a}f(z)$

Its my assignment and am not even sure where to start from!

Comment: This is not true, at least not without additional assumptions.

Comment: Oh yes @mrf , $f(z)$ needs be an even function, I have included that in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. For example, if $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$, then
$$
\operatorname{Res}_{\underline{z=1}}f(z)=1
$$
whereas
$$
\operatorname{Res}_{\underline{z=-1}}f(z)=0
$$

---

What is true is that
$$
\operatorname{Res}_{\underline{z=a}}f(z)=
-\operatorname{Res}_{\underline{z=-a}}f(-z)
$$
Just write the Laurent expansion for $f$ at $a$, assumed to be an isolated singularity:
$$
f(z)=\dots+\frac{c_{-1}}{z-a}+c_0+c_1(z-a)+\dotsb
$$
Then
$$
f(-z)=\dots+\frac{c_{-1}}{-z-a}+c_0+c_1(-z-a)+\dotsb=
\dots+\frac{-c_{-1}}{z-(-a)}+c_0-c_1(z-(-a))+\dotsb
$$
is the Laurent expansion for $f(-z)$ at $-a$ and the residue is $-c_{-1}$.

You can do it similarly with integrals.